# Dropzone control with Hot Towel Template (Knockout and Durandal)

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, durandal, hottowel, dropzone.js

I'm facing a problem in loading Dropzone  control in Hot Towel Template I used  dropzone-amd-module and included it as a dependency

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'text': '../Scripts/text',
        'durandal': '../Scripts/durandal',
        'plugins': '../Scripts/durandal/plugins',
        'transitions': '../Scripts/durandal/transitions',
        'dropzone': '../Scripts/dropzone-amd-module'

    }
});
```

and in my dashboard.js

```
define(['services/logger','dropzone'], function (logger,Dropzone) {
    var title = 'Home';
    var vm = {
        title: title
    };

    return vm;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {

           Dropzone.options.dropzoneJsForm = {

            //prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
            autoProcessQueue: false,

            init: function () {
                var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all");
                var myDropzone = this; //closure

                submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    myDropzone.processQueue(); //tell Dropzone to process all queued files
                });

            },
            addRemoveLinks: true

        };
        logger.log(title + ' View Activated', null, title, true);
        return true;
    }
});
```

but I got this error

> Uncaught Error: Failed to load routed module (dashboard/dashboard).
>   Details: Module name "emitter" has not been loaded yet for context: _.
>   Use require([])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed those steps to solve the problem

1- include dropzone.js script BEFORE require.js in the index page 
2- DO NOT include it in main.js as require configuration dependency 
3- create dropzone element programatically in the attached event as follows

```
 function attached(view) {
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzoneJsForm", { url: "/file/post", autoProcessQueue: false });
    }
```

so my controller will be as follows

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
    var title = 'Details';


    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        title: title,
        attached: attached,
    };

    return vm;

    function attached(view) {
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzoneJsForm", { url: "/file/post", autoProcessQueue: false });
    }

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {


       logger.log(title + ' View Activated', null, title, true);
        return true;
    }
});
```